# How to get programmatically all Groups from a site collection

Tags: development, groups

I need to know all groups in my site collection... If I use

```
  using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite))
                {
                    using (SPWeb scWeb = scSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        foreach(SPGroup spg in scWeb.Groups)
                        {
                            debug += spg.Name + "!!!";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The only group I get are groups which have Permissions on the site... How can I get also the groups that has no permission on the site but exists (and has permission in subsites)?
There is an easy way or I have to loop on childs and get new groups from there??

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's wrong with just going to `/_layouts/groups.aspx` on your rootweb? It lists all groups existing on your site

Comment: Programmatically =/ So i must use the SP Api!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need SPWeb.SiteGroups ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitegroups.aspx)) which includes all groups that exist in the site collection.

For further details, please refer to: http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2007/09/spwebgroups-vs-spwebsitegroups.html

Comment: References are very nice, but simply saying `foreach (SPGroup group in scWeb.SiteGroups)` might have been nicer than casting someone off to a link right away, though.

Comment: @vapcguy, the foreach statement is already exists in the question body. So I don't see the need to copy it into the answer because the question was not about the way to deal with the collection of the groups - only about which collection is right for the case. The only thing that needs to be changed in the code from the question is the SPWeb's property containing the required groups. And that's what my answer is about exactly. IMHO, the typical useful answer is not required to be so simple as copy-paste. There's no need to follow the links, the answer is right at the first 4 words of the text.

Comment: Except when I read your answer, I didn't realize how you were applying `SPWeb.SiteGroups`, especially since `.Groups` was already there, until I looked at the links and figured out the difference from that.  Simplicity for those that might stumble upon this, especially to those new to this concept as I was, was all I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this article.

[Programmatically get SharePoint Users with Group Name](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/programmatically-get-sharepoint-users.html)

Hope this helps You!

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.