# How to programmatically get all groups that have permissions on site?

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, groups, sub-site

I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28674/how-to-get-programmatically-all-groups-from-a-site-collection) question and that person was asking how to get all the groups from a site, but instead he already has code that returns groups that have permissions on the site. And that is what I am looking for.
So basically, I need to be able to show all the groups that have permissions (such as edit and read permissions) on a site or subsite. I have about 12 subsites and they all have different groups with permissions, and my goal is to show all the groups per subsite. 
Here's the code he has in his post:

```
using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite))
            {
                using (SPWeb scWeb = scSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    foreach(SPGroup spg in scWeb.Groups)
                    {
                        debug += spg.Name + "!!!";
                    }
                }
            }
```

However, his code doesn't work for me. I've never had to user "SPSite" or "SPWeb" or "SPContext" or "SPGroup". Instead I always managed to get my WinForm to work with just "Site" or "Web" or "Context" or "Group".
I've made a WinForm in C# and I want to make it so that I can select a subsite and it should then show me the groups and their permissions per subsite. I am using a nice combobox with subsites in it and some labels that show me how many pages/libraries/lists and such are present in the selected subsite. The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the groups that have permissions on the subsite.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! I've been searching for this for over a week now and I'm starting to get really desparate. 

Code example of my form, to give you an idea of how I use Web and such (this particular piece fills the combobox with my main site (Q-Gids) and its subsites):

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string url = "https://url-to-my-intranet-site.be";
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);

            context.Load(web.Webs);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Q-Gids");

            foreach (Web website in web.Webs)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(website.Title);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I fear I might have misphrased my question a bit, but it turns out that it is solved now. So for those who need to get all the groups in a subsite along with their permissions, here's a piece of code that might be of any help to you:

```
   using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
   {
      Web web = context.Web;
      ListCollection pageList = web.Lists;
      RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = web.RoleAssignments;
      context.Load(web.Webs);
      context.Load(web.Lists);
      context.Load(context.Site.OpenWeb(comboValue1), p => p.Url, p => p.Title);
      context.Load(context.Site.OpenWeb(comboValue1).SiteGroups);
      context.Load(context.Site.OpenWeb(comboValue1).RoleAssignments.Groups);
      context.Load(web, p => p.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, p => p.EffectiveBasePermissions, p => p.FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject);
      context.Load(roleAssignments.Groups);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      GroupCollection o1;
      o1 = context.Site.OpenWeb(comboValue1).RoleAssignments.Groups;

      foreach (Group gp2 in o1)
      {
         RoleAssignment oRoleAssignment = web.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(gp2);
         context.Load(gp2);
         context.Load(gp2.Users);
         context.Load(oRoleAssignment, p => p.RoleDefinitionBindings);
         context.ExecuteQuery();
         int counter2 = 0;
         string tempString = "";
         int fixedCounter = oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Count();
         foreach (RoleDefinition inRole in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
         {
            counter2++;
            tempString += inRole.Name.ToString();
            if (counter2 != fixedCounter)
            {
               tempString += ", ";
            }
         }
         ML.Add(new SmallColumnHolder { cGroupName = gp2.Title.ToString(), cGroupPermissions = tempString });
      }
      foreach (var i in ML.ToArray())
      {
         ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(new string[] { i.cGroupName, i.cGroupPermissions });
         listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listView1.Items.Add(li); });
      }
   }
```

comboValue1 is the selected value from a combobox, which holds the name of a subsite. I first add each group from that subsite to a list, and then loop through that list and for each item in it, I add it to a listview. All of this is happening in a background worker, hence the delegate. Thank you everyone who helped me with this. :)

Comment: Hi Magali: I've responded with a comment regarding the answers from Brandon C but you are basically using the Client-Side Object Model which is why the examples you're seeing look a bit different and why most examples show classes prefixed with "SP": those are examples based on the Server-Side Object Model. Check out this for examples about getting the SharePoint Groups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.groupcollection(v=office.15).aspx Hope this helps move you on a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to get group permissions, you use the SPWeb.RoleAssignments function built into sharepoint.  Here is a link to the webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.roleassignments.aspx

Then write code to loop through each web in your site collection, grabbing each group in those webs.  Let's say you want to write to console each group that has the "Design" role.  Then have your code look like:

```
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{
SPRoleAssignmentCollection oRoleAssignments = web.RoleAssignments;
if(oRoleAssignments -eq "Designer") {
      write-host "Group Name with Design Permission: " $oRoleAssignments.Member.Name
}
}
```

Something like that at least.  My code doesn't include looping through all the webs in your site collection, but you get the idea.  That's how you reference group roles.

Comment: But I can't use SPWeb, anything that has SP at the beginning doesn't work. I always used just "Web" instead of "SPWeb", when I use "SPWeb" it gives me the error that the namespace can't be found even though I have "using Microsoft.SharePoint;" at the top of my code...

Comment: But you said you got it to work without the "SP" part?  Maybe you are including a file that uses a namespace overwriting SPWeb and SPSite?

Comment: I can use Web and ListCollection and Site and ClientContext and such, and I can connect to my SharePoint environment just fine with that, but everything I find online always begins with "SP" like "SPWeb" and that doesn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post an example snippet of code to show what you mean?  The only way I can think of the terms being changed from SPWeb to just Web is if you are using namespaces to overwrite the term.

Comment: I added an example of my code in my original question.

Comment: Looking at your question again, it might just be that since you are using WinForms to write your code, it is replacing the need to classify "SPWeb" in your code, instead just using "Web".  All of the code you see written elsewhere is most likely written in Powershell, or in any IDE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15025/discussion-between-magali-and-brandon-c).

Comment: Sorry, currently doing research for work, can't chat.  Just thought I could pop in real quick to answer the question, didn't seem difficult at the time, haha.  If I find any more information along the way, I will let you know

Comment: I see, thanks in advance though. :)

Comment: Just to be clear Site and Web and ClientContext etc. are part all of the Client-side Object Model and as Magali is using a WinForm it makes sense that CSOM is being used.  Magali: you need to look for examples using the Client-side Object Model or CSOM. :)

Comment: Man, I was trying to remember the name of it, thank you for posting!  I knew it had something to do with the WinForm, I just couldn't for the life of me put those two together, haha

Answer (score 0):

Prints out all the groups for the SPWeb and the group's role names:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/sites/sitecollection/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("test"))
    {
        foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in web.RoleAssignments)
        {
            if (roleAssignment.Member is SPGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group: " + roleAssignment.Member.Name);
                foreach (SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition in roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + roleDefinition.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using CSOM, this is server side code